# How to do GROUP BY with CASE in jOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have query like this:

```sql
SELECT bm.name
FROM parent bm
ORDER BY CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM children bl 
              WHERE bl.user_id = 'd012345e-22sc-44e5-ade7-ffdce74af05e' 
                AND bl.parent_id=bm.parent_id)
    THEN 1 END;
```

Where I try to filter data with specific value from another table and it works fine, but I don't understand how to do this in jOOQ.

Comment: Just use your query as [native](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-executor/).

Comment: What are you struggling with, specifically? The `CASE`? The `EXISTS` subquery? I mean, all SQL translates to jOOQ pretty 1:1, but perhaps, you're running into a *specific* problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you're struggling with, but remember that everything you attempt to do in jOOQ can almost always be translated 1:1 from SQL. If you're struggling with that, you can always use the [online translation service to translate SQL to jOOQ (Java)](https://www.jooq.org/translate/).

I'm assuming, the problems you're having is either related to:

- [`CASE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/)
- [`EXISTS`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/exists-predicate/)
- [Aliased tables](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/)

Assuming you're using [the code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). and you have the usual static imports (e.g. `import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;`), write:

```java
Parent bm = PARENT.as("bm");
Children bl = CHILDREN.as("bl");

ctx.select(bm.NAME)
   .from(bm)
   .orderBy(when(
       exists(
           selectOne()
           .from(bl)
           .where(bl.USER_ID.eq("d012345e-22sc-44e5-ade7-ffdce74af05e"))
           .and(bl.PARENT_ID.eq(bm.PARENT_ID))
       ),
       1
   ))
   .fetch();
```